# NASM Reverse an integer array

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, stack, nasm

Conceptually, I'm trying to push the values onto the stack and pop them off in "opposite" order.  In practice, I think I'm doing that but I'm not sure.  The array I'm passing is defined in the `section .data` as `array: dd 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` and the size is being passed as an int value (3 = 3 elements).  When I run the application, it links and assembles but the array is not reversed.

```
push dword array
push dword [arrayLen]
call reverse
add esp, 8

; other stuff

reverse:
    push ebp                    ; setup stack
    mov ebp,esp 
    sub esp,0x40                ; 64 bytes of local stack space 

    ; put parameters into registers
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]           ; array
    mov edx, [ebp+8]            ; len

    ; set up loop
    mov ecx, 0

    ; push all the values onto the stack
    .loopPush:
        mov eax, 4
        mul ecx
        push dword [ebx]
        add ecx, 1
        cmp ecx, edx
            jl .loopPush
    mov ecx, 0

    ; pop all the values from the stack
    .loopPop:
        mov eax, 4
        mul edx
        pop dword [ebx+edx]
        add ecx, 1
        cmp ecx, edx
            jl .loopPop

    ; print the array
    push dword [ebp+12]
    push dword [ebp+8]
    call printArray
    add esp, 8

    .end:
        mov esp,ebp             ; undo "sub esp,0x40" above 
        pop ebp
        mov eax, ebx                ; return the reversed array
        ret
```

The print function accurately prints whatever I give it so I'm about 90% certain it's not an issue when printing.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a debugger to find out where your code goes wrong. Also, comment your code, especially if you expect others to help you. Furthermore, the trivial algorithm to reverse an array is just to walk from both ends and swap items until you meet in the middle. No calculate-halfway-point is needed, and no messing with the stack either.

Comment: I don't need to calculate half way point like this, just push all values then pop all values.  There may be other ways to do this but I'm mostly curious as to why this doesn't work.  I don't have a debugger right now, any suggestions would be great.

Comment: writing assembler code with no debugger - good luck with that

Comment: Why would you want to use an algorithm that makes a copy of the array when its not needed?  The stack is a copy. If you think of the array as a "prebuilt" stack, pop elements and put them immediately in the correct location, you have the standard algorithm that works from the ends inward.

Comment: If you don't have a debugger the solution isn't to ask others to debug your code. The solution is to get a debugger ;)

Comment: A debugger is much less likely to give me examples and possibly links to documentation than SO!  More importantly, a debugger doesn't really help me understand how my issue relates to the larger world of assembly.  If I'm doing something wrong, I'd rather know how and why my solution is inferior to other options.  A debugger can help me fix my code in the moment but won't give me the level of understanding I look for.  Though suggestions for debuggers would be appreciated as well.  For me, and presumably others, posting to SO is a last ditch effort, I don't post here until I really have to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic) for information about `mul` instruction. After you correct your mul instruction and use of result in your code everything works well. I correct your code as follow :

```
section .data
    array:  dd 1, 2, 3
    arrayLen: dd 3

section .text
global main

main:
    push dword array
    push dword [arrayLen]
    call reverse
    add esp, 8


reverse:
    push ebp        ; setup stack
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 0x40       ; 64 bytes of local stack space

    ; put parameters into registers
    mov ebx, [ebp + 12]           ; array
    mov edi, [ebp + 8]            ; len

    ; set up loop
    mov ecx, 0

; push all the values onto the stack
.loopPush:
    mov eax, 4
    mul ecx
    push dword [ebx + eax]
    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, edi
    jl .loopPush
    mov ecx, 0

; pop all the values from the stack
.loopPop:
    mov eax, 4
    mul ecx
    pop dword [ebx + eax]
    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, edi
    jl .loopPop

; print the array
    ;push dword [ebp+12]
    ;push dword [ebp+8]
    ;call printArray
    ;add esp, 8

.end:
    mov esp,ebp ; undo "sub esp,0x40" above                                                                     
    pop ebp
    mov eax, ebx    ; return the reversed array
    ret
```

Sorry I must comment some part of your code.

Comment: thank you for the link to documentation.  I looked all over for something like that and couldn't find it anywhere!